# Display model in View

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, code-first, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm an MVC Noob but I really want to gain some experience using MVC so I am trying recreate an Asp Classic project using MVC. The code below does't not display the list of meals associated with a menu on the Meals/Index page.

I have read about several different patterns, ninject and auto mapper however, from what I can tell it's nothing like that is necessary when dealing with a simple association.

I would just like to add Meals to a Menu and aggregate the meal prices for each menu.

Models:

```
public class Meal
{   [Key]
    public int MealId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public int MenuId { get; set; }
}


public class Menu
{
    [Key]
    public int MenuId { get; set; }
    public DateTime WeekendServed { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public List<Model> Meals { get; set; //Menus have meals. 
}
```

Menu Controller:

```
 public ViewResult Index()
 {
    return View(unitOfWork.MenuRepository.Get());
 }
```

`Menu/Index/`:

```
@model IEnumerable<Skimos.Models.Meal>
----

<Table Headers>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.WeekendServed)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Price)
        </td>
        <td>
            @foreach (var meal in item.Meals)
            {
                @Html.Display(meal.Name)
                @Html.Display(meal.Description)
                @Html.Display(meal.Price.ToString())
            }
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.MenuId }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.MenuId }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.MenuId })
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

MenuRepository
     `public IQueryable Menus
     {
         get { return context.Menus; }
     }`
Edit:

Comment: Can you show the code for `unitOfWork.MenuRepository.Get()` and also, what is the view strongly typed to?

Comment: Don't implement a Repository/Unit of Work pattern around Entity Framework. EF *already* employs this pattern (`DbContext` is your UoW, your `DbSet`s are your repositories). If you want to abstract the logic of using EF away (which is a good idea), then implement something like a service pattern instead.

Comment: @ChrisPratt any link on how to integrate service pattern in EF? , EF by provind DBSet and DBContext gives you all things how to better control developer not allowing adding object to certain dbsets , not allowing certain operations on DBSet?

Comment: The service pattern is generic: you can find much better explanations than I could provide here elsewhere online. The general idea, though, is that you wrap you selection logic up into a method on your service. For example, if you wanted to do something like get all published posts from the last month, in your controller, you would merely call something like `myService.GetPublishedPostsForLastMonth()` and do all your EF calls in that method. Of course, for something like that, you'd probably want to create a slightly more generic method that could handle different months, but you get the idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that EF requires two things for list-type navigation properties: 1) an `ICollection` type and 2) `virtual` on the property:

So if you change your `Meals` property to the following, you should be good:

```
public virtual ICollection<Meal> Meals { get; set; }
```

The reason for `ICollection` is that the return value from EF will be an `IQueryable` type. The reason for the virtual is that EF actually returns proxy classes instead of the actual model class. These proxies have overrides for the navigation properties that return the datasets. If your property is not virtual, EF can't override it.

Comment: I may not have asked the right question before. I would have never even considered trying to model the Meal Class with a constructor that contained Menus... Is this EF implementing IoC? I would be happy to select your answer as correct if you could provide some insight about how I "fixed / hacked" a way to solve the issue I was having. Thanks for listening.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're talking about. However, your "fix" is *very* bad design. Namely, you have 6 separate `Menu` navigation properties,  6 different foreign key's to `Meal` on `Menu`. It doesn't matter if you will only have 6 meals, because this is *plainly* a M2M relationship and should be modeled as such. What if tomorrow, you actually need 7 meals. Now you have to open up the classes to add another and you've broken the open-closed principle. If you find yourself doing `Something1, Something2, Something3, ...`  *you're doing it wrong*.

Comment: I understand, I removed it from my solution and this page. Thanks for your input.